# insert document if not found

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor server code tries to insert a different document every time inside a loop if it does not exist using `upsert`, it only inserts the first document but not the followings even though they are different.  What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```js
MyCol = new Mongo.Collection('myCol');

MyCol.before.insert(function(userId, doc) {
  doc.userId = userId;
  doc.createdAt = Date.now();
});

//the following is inside a loop where C and date changes
MyCol.upsert({
  userId: userId
}, {
  $set: {
    a: 'A',
    b: 'B',
    c: C,
    date: date
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expand your *query* parameter for your `upsert`:

```
MyCol.upsert({ userId: userId },{ $set: ... });
```

You only have one parameter in your query: the `userId`. Since `c` and `date` are changing you need to include them in your query as well:

```
MyCol.upsert({ userId: userId, c: C, date: date },
  { $set: { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: C, date: date }});
```

You might even need to include `a` and `b` in your query if they are part of what makes a document unique.

Alternatively you can also use `.update()` with the `upsert` flag set to `true`:

```
MyCol.update(query,modifier,{ upsert: true })
```